# How do I create a RegEx that matches a string that starts and finishes with a percentage sign?

Tags: c#, regex

In a given program, a string should start and finish with a percentage sign and can contain any number of characters in-between.  Therefore, the following strings should be valid:

- `"%%"`
- `"% %"`
- `"%a%"`
- `"%1%"`
- `"% a1a %"`
- `"%%%"`

The following strings (for example) would therefore be invalid:

- `" %%"`
- `"%% "`
- `" % "`
- `" a%%b "`

I am trying to validate these using regular expressions but cannot figure the correct expression.  In C# I currently have:

```
Regex.IsMatch(stringToValidate, "%.*%")
```

All strings provided above currently match.  But I do not want it to match the set of invalid strings.

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Have you tried `^%.*%$`?

Comment: What is it incorrectly matching or failing to match?

Comment: Yes, it is failing to match.  I have updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an "anchor" (in your case two: start "^" and end "$" of string).
Otherwise your pattern will match anywhere *inside* the complete string and thus 
`" %...% "` or `abc%...%xx` would also match.

Thus, use:

```
 "^%.*%$"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `^%.*%$` with the multi line flag:

https://regex101.com/r/QDX5h3/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
bool foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(stringToValidate, "^%.*%$");
```

---

### [image]

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LdPe3u/1)